# Extending abstract class c++

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I am extending an abstract class, overriding the pure virtual methods, but when I compile I still get an error:

> cannot allocate an object of abstract type   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘CefRequestHandler::MyResourceHandler’

The functions in the error message are from the parent class of the class I extended. Why is this happening?  Why is it pulling pure virtual methods from parent of my extended class? How can I get around this?

If it helps, I have not done anything to override the methods in my class, basically listed them in my class without the virtual written in front of them. see below.

The method I am using to return my class:

```
virtual CefRefPtr<CefResourceHandler> GetResourceHandler(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request) {

    //return NULL;
    return new MyResourceHandler();
  }
```

The class that contains the method:

```
class CefRequestCallback : public virtual CefBase {
 public:
  ///
  // Continue the url request. If |allow| is true the request will be continued.
  // Otherwise, the request will be canceled.
  ///
  /*--cef(capi_name=cont)--*/
  virtual void Continue(bool allow) =0;

  ///
  // Cancel the url request.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void Cancel() =0;
};


///
// Implement this interface to handle events related to browser requests. The
// methods of this class will be called on the thread indicated.
///
/*--cef(source=client)--*/
class CefRequestHandler : public virtual CefBase {
 public:
  typedef cef_return_value_t ReturnValue;
  typedef cef_termination_status_t TerminationStatus;
  typedef cef_urlrequest_status_t URLRequestStatus;
  typedef cef_window_open_disposition_t WindowOpenDisposition;

  ///
  // Called on the UI thread before browser navigation. Return true to cancel
  // the navigation or false to allow the navigation to proceed. The |request|
  // object cannot be modified in this callback.
  // CefLoadHandler::OnLoadingStateChange will be called twice in all cases.
  // If the navigation is allowed CefLoadHandler::OnLoadStart and
  // CefLoadHandler::OnLoadEnd will be called. If the navigation is canceled
  // CefLoadHandler::OnLoadError will be called with an |errorCode| value of
  // ERR_ABORTED.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnBeforeBrowse(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                              CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                              CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                              bool is_redirect) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the UI thread before OnBeforeBrowse in certain limited cases
  // where navigating a new or different browser might be desirable. This
  // includes user-initiated navigation that might open in a special way (e.g.
  // links clicked via middle-click or ctrl + left-click) and certain types of
  // cross-origin navigation initiated from the renderer process (e.g.
  // navigating the top-level frame to/from a file URL). The |browser| and
  // |frame| values represent the source of the navigation. The
  // |target_disposition| value indicates where the user intended to navigate
  // the browser based on standard Chromium behaviors (e.g. current tab,
  // new tab, etc). The |user_gesture| value will be true if the browser
  // navigated via explicit user gesture (e.g. clicking a link) or false if it
  // navigated automatically (e.g. via the DomContentLoaded event). Return true
  // to cancel the navigation or false to allow the navigation to proceed in the
  // source browser's top-level frame.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnOpenURLFromTab(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                const CefString& target_url,
                                WindowOpenDisposition target_disposition,
                                bool user_gesture) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread before a resource request is loaded. The |request|
  // object may be modified. Return RV_CONTINUE to continue the request
  // immediately. Return RV_CONTINUE_ASYNC and call CefRequestCallback::
  // Continue() at a later time to continue or cancel the request
  // asynchronously. Return RV_CANCEL to cancel the request immediately.
  // 
  ///
  /*--cef(default_retval=RV_CONTINUE)--*/
  virtual ReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback) {
    return RV_CONTINUE;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread before a resource is loaded. To allow the resource
  // to load normally return NULL. To specify a handler for the resource return
  // a CefResourceHandler object. The |request| object should not be modified in
  // this callback.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  ***virtual CefRefPtr<CefResourceHandler> GetResourceHandler(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request) {

    //return NULL;
    return new MyResourceHandler();
  }***

class MyResourceHandler : public CefResourceHandler
{
public:
MyResourceHandler() 
//offset_(0)
{}

 bool ProcessRequest(CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                              CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) ;



   void GetResponseHeaders(CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response,
                                  int64& response_length,
                                  CefString& redirectUrl) ;


   bool ReadResponse(void* data_out,
                            int bytes_to_read,
                            int& bytes_read,
                            CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) ;

  bool CanGetCookie(const CefCookie& cookie) { return true; }


   bool CanSetCookie(const CefCookie& cookie) { return true; }


   void Cancel() ;
 // bool ProcessRequest (CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
//CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback){

//CefRefPtr<CefRequest> cef   = CefRequest::Create();
//cef = request;
//CefRequest::ReferrerPolicy origin = REFERRER_POLICY_ALWAYS;
//request->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);
//cef->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);

//}

//IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(MyResourceHandler);
//IMPLEMENT_LOCKING(MyResourceHandler);
};

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when a resource load is redirected. The |request|
  // parameter will contain the old URL and other request-related information.
  // The |new_url| parameter will contain the new URL and can be changed if
  // desired. The |request| object cannot be modified in this callback.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnResourceRedirect(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                                  CefString& new_url) {}

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when a resource response is received. To allow the
  // resource to load normally return false. To redirect or retry the resource
  // modify |request| (url, headers or post body) and return true. The
  // |response| object cannot be modified in this callback.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnResourceResponse(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread to optionally filter resource response content.
  // |request| and |response| represent the request and response respectively
  // and cannot be modified in this callback.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual CefRefPtr<CefResponseFilter> GetResourceResponseFilter(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
      CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response) {
    return NULL;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when a resource load has completed. |request| and
  // |response| represent the request and response respectively and cannot be
  // modified in this callback. |status| indicates the load completion status.
  // |received_content_length| is the number of response bytes actually read.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnResourceLoadComplete(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                                      CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response,
                                      URLRequestStatus status,
                                      int64 received_content_length) {}

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when the browser needs credentials from the user.
  // |isProxy| indicates whether the host is a proxy server. |host| contains the
  // hostname and |port| contains the port number. |realm| is the realm of the
  // challenge and may be empty. |scheme| is the authentication scheme used,
  // such as "basic" or "digest", and will be empty if the source of the request
  // is an FTP server. Return true to continue the request and call
  // CefAuthCallback::Continue() either in this method or at a later time when
  // the authentication information is available. Return false to cancel the
  // request immediately.
  ///
  /*--cef(optional_param=realm,optional_param=scheme)--*/
  virtual bool GetAuthCredentials(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                  bool isProxy,
                                  const CefString& host,
                                  int port,
                                  const CefString& realm,
                                  const CefString& scheme,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefAuthCallback> callback) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when JavaScript requests a specific storage quota
  // size via the webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota function. |origin_url| is the
  // origin of the page making the request. |new_size| is the requested quota
  // size in bytes. Return true to continue the request and call
  // CefRequestCallback::Continue() either in this method or at a later time to
  // grant or deny the request. Return false to cancel the request immediately.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnQuotaRequest(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                              const CefString& origin_url,
                              int64 new_size,
                              CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the UI thread to handle requests for URLs with an unknown
  // protocol component. Set |allow_os_execution| to true to attempt execution
  // via the registered OS protocol handler, if any.
  // SECURITY WARNING: YOU SHOULD USE THIS METHOD TO ENFORCE RESTRICTIONS BASED
  // ON SCHEME, HOST OR OTHER URL ANALYSIS BEFORE ALLOWING OS EXECUTION.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnProtocolExecution(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                   const CefString& url,
                                   bool& allow_os_execution) {}

  ///
  // Called on the UI thread to handle requests for URLs with an invalid
  // SSL certificate. Return true and call CefRequestCallback::Continue() either
  // in this method or at a later time to continue or cancel the request. Return
  // false to cancel the request immediately. If
  // CefSettings.ignore_certificate_errors is set all invalid certificates will
  // be accepted without calling this method.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnCertificateError(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      cef_errorcode_t cert_error,
      const CefString& request_url,
      CefRefPtr<CefSSLInfo> ssl_info,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the browser process UI thread when a plugin has crashed.
  // |plugin_path| is the path of the plugin that crashed.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnPluginCrashed(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                               const CefString& plugin_path) {}

  ///
  // Called on the browser process UI thread when the render view associated
  // with |browser| is ready to receive/handle IPC messages in the render
  // process.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnRenderViewReady(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) {}

  ///
  // Called on the browser process UI thread when the render process
  // terminates unexpectedly. |status| indicates how the process
  // terminated.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnRenderProcessTerminated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                         TerminationStatus status) {}
};
```

Below is the class I created that is causing errors:

```
class MyResourceHandler : public CefResourceHandler
{
public:
MyResourceHandler() 
//offset_(0)
{}

 bool ProcessRequest(CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                              CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) ;



   void GetResponseHeaders(CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response,
                                  int64& response_length,
                                  CefString& redirectUrl) ;


   bool ReadResponse(void* data_out,
                            int bytes_to_read,
                            int& bytes_read,
                            CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) ;

  bool CanGetCookie(const CefCookie& cookie) { return true; }


   bool CanSetCookie(const CefCookie& cookie) { return true; }


   void Cancel() ;

};
```

CEFResourceHandler class (class I extended):

```
#ifndef CEF_INCLUDE_CEF_RESOURCE_HANDLER_H_
#define CEF_INCLUDE_CEF_RESOURCE_HANDLER_H_
#pragma once

#include "include/cef_base.h"
#include "include/cef_browser.h"
#include "include/cef_callback.h"
#include "include/cef_cookie.h"
#include "include/cef_request.h"
#include "include/cef_response.h"

///
// Class used to implement a custom request handler interface. The methods of
// this class will always be called on the IO thread.
///
/*--cef(source=client)--*/
class CefResourceHandler : public virtual CefBase {
 public:
  ///
  // Begin processing the request. To handle the request return true and call
  // CefCallback::Continue() once the response header information is available
  // (CefCallback::Continue() can also be called from inside this method if
  // header information is available immediately). To cancel the request return
  // false.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool ProcessRequest(CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                              CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) =0;

  ///
  // Retrieve response header information. If the response length is not known
  // set |response_length| to -1 and ReadResponse() will be called until it
  // returns false. If the response length is known set |response_length|
  // to a positive value and ReadResponse() will be called until it returns
  // false or the specified number of bytes have been read. Use the |response|
  // object to set the mime type, http status code and other optional header
  // values. To redirect the request to a new URL set |redirectUrl| to the new
  // URL.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void GetResponseHeaders(CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response,
                                  int64& response_length,
                                  CefString& redirectUrl) =0;

  ///
  // Read response data. If data is available immediately copy up to
  // |bytes_to_read| bytes into |data_out|, set |bytes_read| to the number of
  // bytes copied, and return true. To read the data at a later time set
  // |bytes_read| to 0, return true and call CefCallback::Continue() when the
  // data is available. To indicate response completion return false.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool ReadResponse(void* data_out,
                            int bytes_to_read,
                            int& bytes_read,
                            CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) =0;

  ///
  // Return true if the specified cookie can be sent with the request or false
  // otherwise. If false is returned for any cookie then no cookies will be sent
  // with the request.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool CanGetCookie(const CefCookie& cookie) { return true; }

  ///
  // Return true if the specified cookie returned with the response can be set
  // or false otherwise.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool CanSetCookie(const CefCookie& cookie) { return true; }

  ///
  // Request processing has been canceled.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void Cancel() =0;
};

#endif  // CEF_INCLUDE_CEF_RESOURCE_HANDLER_H_
```

Notice how the errors start when my custom class is called in the return statement.

Error message output:

```
In file included from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_client.h:56:0,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/ctocpp/browser_ctocpp.h:24,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/cpptoc/context_menu_handler_cpptoc.cc:14:
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_request_handler.h: In member function ‘virtual CefRefPtr<CefResourceHandler> CefRequestHandler::GetResourceHandler(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser>, CefRefPtr<CefFrame>, CefRefPtr<CefRequest>)’:
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_request_handler.h:159:27: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘CefRequestHandler::MyResourceHandler’
  return MyResourceHandler();
                           ^
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_request_handler.h:163:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘CefRequestHandler::MyResourceHandler’:
 class MyResourceHandler : public CefResourceHandler
       ^
In file included from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_context_menu_handler.h:41:0,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/cpptoc/context_menu_handler_cpptoc.h:21,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/cpptoc/context_menu_handler_cpptoc.cc:13:
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_base.h:60:16: note:   virtual void CefBase::AddRef() const
   virtual void AddRef() const =0;
                ^
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_base.h:66:16: note:   virtual bool CefBase::Release() const
   virtual bool Release() const =0;
                ^
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_base.h:71:16: note:   virtual bool CefBase::HasOneRef() const
   virtual bool HasOneRef() const =0;
                ^
In file included from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_client.h:56:0,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/cpptoc/client_cpptoc.h:21,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/cpptoc/client_cpptoc.cc:13:
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_request_handler.h: In member function ‘virtual CefRefPtr<CefResourceHandler> CefRequestHandler::GetResourceHandler(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser>, CefRefPtr<CefFrame>, CefRefPtr<CefRequest>)’:
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_request_handler.h:159:27: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘CefRequestHandler::MyResourceHandler’
  return MyResourceHandler();
                           ^
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_request_handler.h:163:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘CefRequestHandler::MyResourceHandler’:
 class MyResourceHandler : public CefResourceHandler
       ^
In file included from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_client.h:41:0,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/cpptoc/client_cpptoc.h:21,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/cpptoc/client_cpptoc.cc:13:
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_base.h:60:16: note:   virtual void CefBase::AddRef() const
   virtual void AddRef() const =0;
                ^
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_base.h:66:16: note:   virtual bool CefBase::Release() const
   virtual bool Release() const =0;
                ^
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_base.h:71:16: note:   virtual bool CefBase::HasOneRef() const
   virtual bool HasOneRef() const =0;
                ^
In file included from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_client.h:56:0,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/ctocpp/browser_ctocpp.h:24,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/cpptoc/display_handler_cpptoc.cc:14:
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_request_handler.h: In member function ‘virtual CefRefPtr<CefResourceHandler> CefRequestHandler::GetResourceHandler(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser>, CefRefPtr<CefFrame>, CefRefPtr<CefRequest>)’:
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_request_handler.h:159:27: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘CefRequestHandler::MyResourceHandler’
  return MyResourceHandler();
                           ^
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_request_handler.h:163:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘CefRequestHandler::MyResourceHandler’:
 class MyResourceHandler : public CefResourceHandler
       ^
In file included from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_display_handler.h:41:0,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/cpptoc/display_handler_cpptoc.h:21,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/cpptoc/display_handler_cpptoc.cc:13:
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_base.h:60:16: note:   virtual void CefBase::AddRef() const
   virtual void AddRef() const =0;
                ^
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_base.h:66:16: note:   virtual bool CefBase::Release() const
   virtual bool Release() const =0;
                ^
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_base.h:71:16: note:   virtual bool CefBase::HasOneRef() const
   virtual bool HasOneRef() const =0;
                ^
In file included from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_client.h:56:0,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/ctocpp/browser_ctocpp.h:24,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/cpptoc/dialog_handler_cpptoc.cc:14:
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_request_handler.h: In member function ‘virtual CefRefPtr<CefResourceHandler> CefRequestHandler::GetResourceHandler(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser>, CefRefPtr<CefFrame>, CefRefPtr<CefRequest>)’:
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_request_handler.h:159:27: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘CefRequestHandler::MyResourceHandler’
  return MyResourceHandler();
                           ^
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_request_handler.h:163:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘CefRequestHandler::MyResourceHandler’:
 class MyResourceHandler : public CefResourceHandler
       ^
In file included from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_dialog_handler.h:41:0,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/cpptoc/dialog_handler_cpptoc.h:21,
                 from /home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/libcef_dll/cpptoc/dialog_handler_cpptoc.cc:13:
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_base.h:60:16: note:   virtual void CefBase::AddRef() const
   virtual void AddRef() const =0;
                ^
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_base.h:66:16: note:   virtual bool CefBase::Release() const
   virtual bool Release() const =0;
                ^
/home/c/Downloads/cef_binary_3.2704.1432.g60b3718_linux64/include/cef_base.h:71:16: note:   virtual bool CefBase::HasOneRef() const
   virtual bool HasOneRef() const =0;
                ^
make[3]: *** [libcef_dll_wrapper/CMakeFiles/libcef_dll_wrapper.dir/cpptoc/context_menu_handler_cpptoc.cc.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [libcef_dll_wrapper/CMakeFiles/libcef_dll_wrapper.dir/cpptoc/display_handler_cpptoc.cc.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [libcef_dll_wrapper/CMakeFiles/libcef_dll_wrapper.dir/cpptoc/client_cpptoc.cc.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [libcef_dll_wrapper/CMakeFiles/libcef_dll_wrapper.dir/cpptoc/dialog_handler_cpptoc.cc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [libcef_dll_wrapper/CMakeFiles/libcef_dll_wrapper.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [cefsimple/CMakeFiles/cefsimple.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [cefsimple] Error 2
```

---

**Solution**

I added the following to the `MyResourceHandler` class. I had to override the pure virtual functions from the parent class:

```
void AddRef()const {} ;

bool Release() const { return true; }

bool HasOneRef() const { return true; };
```

Comment: Can we see the code for CefResourceHandler?

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also the code that uses the MyResourceHandler class?

Comment: @Daniel This issue is probably a difference between the pure function declarations and the ones you implemented. However, we cannot say anything because we don't know what the virtual functions look like. Also, some of the functions in your posted code are not implemented but we don't know if those are the virtual ones in the error message.

Comment: Use pointers or references to `CefResourceHandler`. Do not create containers of them, as an example`std::vector<CefResourceHandler>`.

Comment: You have instantiated an instance of `MyResourceHandler `, haven't you. If so, things are working as expected since you haven't provided an implementation of `CefRequestHandler::MyResourceHandler`,

Comment: as it says - you didnt defined all pure virtual functions you have

Comment: You're missing overrides from `CefBase`: `AddRef` and others (look at the error message)

Comment: I need to override these even though they are not in the parent class? that is what the errors say but seems like a lot of work to get to extend the CefResoureHandler class.

Comment: Those functions (from CefBase) are pure virtual (`virtual void foo() = 0`) i.e. they come without implementation -> you have to provide their functionality.

Comment: @a lot of work: maybe there exists an *abstract implementation* of this interface (as it looks like something a Java developer put together and in Java there are usually interfaces and abstract base implementations providing most of the functionality while requiring only few operations to be overridden, e.g. [AbstractList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html)).

Answer (score 1):

> The functions in the error message are from the parent class of the
>   class I extended. Why is this happening?

That's how inheritance works in C++.  A class is abstract if it has any pure virtual functions in it.  When you derive a new class from an abstract class, it inherits any pure virtual functions that have not been overridden yet, thus making it abstract as well.  If you need to be able to instantiate that derived class, you must implement any pure virtual functions that remain, not only the ones from its immediate ancestor class, but also from its ancestor classes, because they were inherited into your class and still need to be defined.  An instantiated class cannot have any pure virtual functions.

> Why is it pulling pure virtual methods from parent of my extended class?

Because that is how C++ works.

> How can I get around this?

You need to implement any pure virtual functions that have not already been overridden in any ancestor class.

Comment: "Implement all pure virtual functions from all parent classes, direct and indirect, that you inherited from." ...that have not already been implemented by an intermediary class in the inheritance hierarchy (unless you need to override them, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The solution the `OP` has posted is incorrect and will leak memory as it doesn't implement those functions. `CEF` uses `Reference Counting`, those methods are part of that implementation, they're simply implemented
using the provided **macro**.

```
class MyClass : public CefBase {
 public:
  // Various class methods here...

 private:
  // Various class members here...

  IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(MyClass);  // Provides atomic refcounting implementation.
};

// References a MyClass instance
CefRefPtr<MyClass> my_class = new MyClass();
```

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage.md#markdown-header-reference-counting